# Getting PERMISSION_DENIED error even inside gcp's vm instance when using stackdriver logging with bunyan

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, graphql, stackdriver, bunyan

I'm trying to use stackdriver logger inside a nodejs application with bunyan logger, I'm using it to log graphql requests, and I've been having problems with configuration, I've followed  @google-cloud/logging-bunyan documentation.

The logger is setup like this:

```
import { createLogger } from 'bunyan';
import { LoggingBunyan } from '@google-cloud/logging-bunyan';


const streams = [{ stream: process.stdout, level: 'info' as 'info' }];


if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'staging' || process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'production') {
  const loggingBunyan = new LoggingBunyan();
  streams.push(loggingBunyan.stream('info'));
}


export const logger = createLogger({
  name: 'backend-logger',
  streams,
});
```

And the usage is setup like this:

```
const logRequests = async (ctx: ParameterizedContext, next: () => Promise<any>) => {
  const auth = await authMiddleware(ctx.request);
  ctx.state.auth = auth;
  const start = Date.now();
  await next();
  const duration = Date.now() - start;


  if (ctx.method === 'POST' && ctx.path === process.env.CLIENT_SERVER_ENDPOINT) {
    const { query } = ctx.request.body;
    const logData = {
      query,
      OrganizationId: auth.user?.OrganizationId,
      UserId: auth.user?.id,
      UserName: auth.user?.name,
      duration,
    };
    if (duration > 200) {
      StackLogger.warn(logData);
    } else {
      StackLogger.info(logData);
    }
  }
};
```

The logger is only setup on staging, problem is, I get only nginx-access logs (before, I wouldn't get that) but not what I've passed to be logged
When I run with PM2, I see the error when it's supposed to log

```
1|api  | {"name":"backend-logger","hostname":"backend","pid":6405,"level":30,"msg":"{ logData:\n   { query:\n      'mutation LoginMutation(\\n  $email: String!\\n  $password: String!\\n) {\\n  login(Email: $email, Password: $password) {\\n    Token\\n  }\\n}\\n',\n     OrganizationId: undefined,\n     UserId: undefined,\n     UserName: undefined,\n     duration: 38 } }","time":"2020-01-09T19:17:45.428Z","v":0}
1|api  |   --> POST /graphql 200 48ms 1.71kb
1|api  | You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
1|api  | Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
1|api  |     at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/home/api/sl_api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:79:24)
1|api  |     at Http2CallStream.call.on (/home/api/sl_api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:155:18)
1|api  |     at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
1|api  |     at Http2CallStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
1|api  |     at process.nextTick (/home/api/sl_api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call-stream.ts:183:14)
1|api  |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

It's inside a gcloud VM instance so I suppose I would have permission to log to stackdriver
So I setup a service account and even then the logs doesn't appear in stackdriver with the same error message in stackdrive.

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work? thanks

Comment: What are your service account assigned roles? have you activate this service account inside the VM instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing the error `Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission`, it seems you're not using the required service account to call the api. As per [the github page](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-bunyan/tree/083d0d2c84e1c2c833734320a1c23fd992c36746#quickstart)  the prerequisites are

1. Select or create a Cloud Platform project.
2. Select or create a Cloud Platform project.
3. Enable the Stackdriver Logging API.
4. [Set up authentication with a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) so you can access the API from your local workstation.

You also mentioned you have enabled the Service account and I am assuming you have provided the correct access as per the [access control guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control).

So, I would like to review the [Explict Auth Setup](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-bunyan/tree/083d0d2c84e1c2c833734320a1c23fd992c36746/samples#explict-auth-setup) to ensure you are calling the API for right project and with correct service account.

NOTE: I am posting this as answer as my current reputation does not support me to comment on your post. Please feel free to let me know if I miss something or if it does not make any sense. I will edit this accordingly.